# Show Maximum value from a Line Textbox

Tags: vb.net

Let's say I have a Textbox with the following values:

```
Lines1 - 180
Lines2 - 190
Lines 3- 200
Lines 4- 220
Lines 5- 230
Lines 6- 260
Lines 7 - 280
Lines 8 - 144
Lines 9 - 125
Lines 10 -160
```

How can I display the line where the highest value is? (For example, if my Textbox contains 250 Digit and some lines, I want to display the line where the maximum value is in another Textbox.

How can I do this for the top `5` highest or `10` highest values in my Textbox? Show Line Value.

Example: Highest Value is `Line 7 - with value 280.`

Output: Textbox1.text - First Line 0 - is nothing. (just space)

```
8
10
13
13
14
17
10
11
14
15
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Updated**

```
Dim myList = TextBox1.Lines.ToList
Dim removedEmptyLinesCount = myList.RemoveAll(Function(str) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
Dim maxValue = myList.Select(Function(line)
                                         Dim res = 0
                                         Integer.TryParse(line, res)
                                         Return res
                                     End Function).Min() ' or Max()
Dim lineIndex = myList.IndexOf(maxValue) + removedEmptyLinesCount
```

This code considering if your TextBox contains any NOT integer values so if inputs like the following:

```
150
60
xx
300
20
yy
45
```

The results should be:

```
maxValue  = 300
lineIndex = 3 (Zero-based index)
```

Comment: But to show the Lower, how can I do? I did the maximum, but I also need the minimum one.

Comment: @NikoMario use `.Min()` instead of `.Max()`

Comment: Did you just replace Max with Min in my code? If you did it should work.

Comment: Not worked correctly. It's a problem with me that the first line does not contain anything, that is, line 0, and starts at line 1, unfortunately displays with -1 all the time the same value of -1. - but in return for the maximum value worked right.

Comment: Show me the input text please

Comment: Updated to remove the empty lines but still count it in index

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with LINQ:

```
Public Function GetMax() As String
  Dim oDirtyLines As List(Of String)
  Dim sMaxLine As String
  Dim iIndex As Integer

  oDirtyLines = Split(TextBox1.Text, vbCrLf).ToList

  Dim oCleanLines = oDirtyLines.Select(Function(Line)
                                         Return New With {
                                                           .Line = Split(Line, "-").First,
                                                           .Value = Split(Line, "-").Last,
                                                           .Index = oDirtyLines.IndexOf(Line)
                                                         }
                                       End Function)

  iIndex = oCleanLines.OrderBy(Function(Line) Line.Value.Trim).Last.Index

  sMaxLine = oDirtyLines(iIndex)

  Return sMaxLine
End Function
```

Comment: How to use for minimum value? Lower value.

Comment: @NikoMario ~ Get `.First.Index` instead of `.Last.Index`.